# Optimizing checking each element of numpy array against a given condition

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, simulation

I have a simulation that looks through a numpy array arbitrarily many times in a given loop to check if any of the elements have exceeded some threshold value. If an element has exceeded the threshold, I need to keep track of which element it was that did so, so I can operate on that particular element. I have a function that does this, but it's a major bottleneck for my code; about 90% of the time spent running the simulation is spent executing this one function.

Here is my function:

```py
    def scanLattice(s_array,t_array,L):
        failures = []
        for i in xrange(L):
            for j in xrange(L):
                if s_array[i,j] >= t_array[i,j]:
                    M = L*j + i
                    failures.append(M)
        return failures
```

`s_array` is the array whose values will be checked; it is [L,L] in size. The `t_array` is also [L,L] and holds the threshold values against which the values in `s_array` are checked. The thresholds are not uniform. A random 1% of the elements of t_array have different threshold values from the rest of the array, which are uniform. I keep track of these nonuniform sites. So I iterate over the rows and columns of `s_array` and check against the corresponding element of `t_array`, adding the index of that site to a list if it satisfies the thresholding condition.

Any advice on how this function could be rewritten in a more efficient way would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at `s_array>=t_array` and `np.where(s_array>=t_array)`.

Answer (score 0):

What you comoute in the function is actually a list of indices in a flattened array, which as 1D view on mulidimentional array. Just compute a mask of value where s_array is greater or equal to t_array. Next implicitly flatten the mask on non-false indices using np.flatnonzero(). There one more issue. Values L*j+i is a flattened index in a transposed array so ndarray.T is applied

```
np.flatnonzero((s_array>=t_array).T)
```